# Convert CSVwriter to inputstream

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, opencsv

I have the following code where I want to write a list of objects onto a csv where I have defined the attributes and items. I want to convert the writer into a input stream so I read the values and do some performed computations. I also want to store this s3 file in a datastore like Amazon S3.

How do I convert the writer into a inputstream. I see no defined api. Can I read the file somehow like CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(csvWriter)?

```
 public CSVWriter convertModelToObject(List attributes, final Class classType) throws IOException {
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), com.opencsv.CSVParser.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
            com.opencsv.CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
    BeanToCsv bean = new BeanToCsv();
    HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<T> mappingStrategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
    mappingStrategy.setType(classType);
    bean.write(mappingStrategy, writer, attributes);
    return writer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing the FileWriter you are using with a PipedWriter, creating it with a PipedReader that you would use when creating the CSVReader.   [You can find an example of the PipedReader Writer here](http://www.concretepage.com/java/java-pipedwriter-pipedreader-example).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can.

The solution is to use `InputStreamReader` to read the file and pass that stream to Buffered reader and read line by line or as you want.

You can refer to this for more methods: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/